# Get Data from Multiple ForeignKey Query Results

Tags: django

I have the following `models.py` set up:

```
Student(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 15, primary_key = True, unique = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    ...

Fine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2)

StudentFines(models.Model):
    student = ForeignKey(Student, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fine = ForeignKey(Fine, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'fines')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

I've assigned two fines to a particular user in my database, so in my `view.py` I have this to get the fines that are assigned to the user:

```
def detail(request, id):
    ...

    fines = StudentFines.objects.filter(student_id = id)
    ...

    context = {
        ...
        'fines': fines,
    }
```

And when I call it in my template with `{% for fine in fines %}A fine.{% endfor %}`, I get two results. Now I want to report the specific details of the fines: the name, description, and value. Eventually I plan to use a form to add an entry directly from the page, but that's future stuff.

I've scoured the Internet and came across several ways to try and get the ForeignKey's data, but none of what I try has worked. I've lost count and I'm pulling my hair out, and I may have just been working on this way too long to notice what the actual solution is. I've tried the following:

In my template, within the `for` loop: `{{ fine.name }}`

Which obviously doesn't work... Then I tried nesting it, like: `{{ fine.fines.name }}` trying to reference the `related_name` in the model. That didn't work, so I went back to my `view.py`:

`fines = Fines.objects.filter(id__in = StudentFines.objects.all())` which does something that I'm not aware of, but it doesn't throw an error. The list is just empty.

`fines = Fines.fines.all()` which is trying to access the `related_name` field, from what I understand?

... As well as a whole host of other things. A lot of the examples I see online are using `.get()` which doesn't work in my case, since it returns more than one result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about call values you need in queryset

```
fines = StudentFines.objects.filter(student_id = id).values('fine__name', 'fine__description', 'fine__value')
```

and then use them in template?

```
{% for fine in fines %}
    {{ fine.fine__name }}
    {{ fine.fine__description }}
    {{ fine.fine__value }}
{% endfor %}
```